# Need to rename XML Element with one of its own properties

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, moxy

I know we can use `@XMLRootElement` annotation to set the name by which we want this to appear in XML after object to xml conversion using JAXB but I am looking about the way so that XML Elements can be renamed with one of its own properties like for the POJO

```
class Field
{
    String fieldName;
    String fieldValue;

    //getter/setter
}
```

after object to xml conversion using JAXB, instead of

```
<Field>
     <fieldName>FirstName</fieldName>
     <fieldValue>Rahul</fieldValue>
</Field
```

I need the above xml formatted as

```
<FirstName>Rahul</FirstName>
```

I know I can simply get this if I declare *FirstName* as String but somehow I need to do as explained above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MOXy/Eclipselink then there is `@XmlVariableNode` annotation available. You would need to specify it on the object that holds the Field (if Field is the root then I fear `@XmlVariableNode` won't help). Example:

```
class Field {
    @XmlTransient
    String fieldName;
    @XmlValue
    String fieldValue;
}

class Holder {
    @XmlVariableNode("fieldName")
    Field field;
}
```

Note that `@XmlVariableNode` is a MOXy specific annotation. It appears to be available since 2.6 version.

Comment: Thanks for your response and one more thing I want to add here is if this Field class would have one more property then is there any way to use that as an attribute for final element like  <firstName id="fieldAttribute">Rahul</firstName>

Comment: See `@XmlAttribute` annotation:
`@XmlAttribute(name="id")String fieldAttribute;`

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can set the name of the properties like you want them to appear by annotating them with `@JsonProperty(...)`.

In your can you can do something as follows:

```
class Field
{
    @JsonProperty("FirstName")
    String fieldName;
    String fieldValue;

    /* Getter-Setters */
}
```

Comment: Yes this can be done easily even using @XmlElement as well but what I want to is little different. Actually I don't want give any hard code name rather it should have to be a runtime value. like fieldName's value become name Field when converted into xml.